# \frontmatter and \mainmatter generate unwanted pages with with the text "figurechapter tablechapter"

Tags: memoir, front-matter

I am working on a book manuscript with a master document which imports chapters from separate documents. The master document class is memoir.

When using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, these commands generate pages with the text "figurechapter tablechapter". These pages disappear when I cross out the `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks.

Here is a simplified version of the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{memoir}


\def\setdocauthor#1{\def\docauthor{#1}}
\def\setdoctitle#1{\def\doctitle{#1}}
\setdocauthor{Author}
\setdoctitle{Title}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine} 
\usepackage{anyfontsize} 

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage[shorthands=off, french, german, italian, latin, british]{babel}
\usepackage[strict]{csquotes}
\let\qq\enquote 
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, url=false, doi=false, isbn=false, eprint=false, useprefix=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage{style}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks, allcolors=NavyBlue,
  linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\docauthor,
  pdftitle=\doctitle}
\usepackage[ open, atend ]{bookmark}
   \bookmarksetup{color=blue}
\let\counterwithout\relax
\let\counterwithin\relax
\usepackage{refcount}

\listfiles 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, quotes, babel, calc, decorations.markings}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox} %for adjusting the size
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{caption}
\colorlet{captiongray}{gray!50!black}

\DeclareCaptionFont{capgray}{\color{captiongray}}
\captionsetup{labelfont={capgray,sf,bf}, textfont={capgray,sf}}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subfig}   
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\relax} 

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{diagbox}[1][]
{skin=bicolor, title=Figure~\thetcbcounter,#1,
  size=title,colback=white, colbacklower=black!10!white}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\include{title/title}

\cleartorecto

\include{acknowledgements/acknowledgements}

\cleartorecto

\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\cleartorecto

\include{introduction/introduction}

\cleartorecto

\part{Part I}
\label{label for part I}

\cleartorecto

\include{Chapter1}
 ...

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\let\counterwithout\relax` what is that supposed to do?

Comment: As Johannes  mentions. `\counterwithin/out` are used in `\front/mainmatter` and relaxing them like this leaves the arguments behind. Whoever added those two lines to your doc better explain to you why they are there.

Comment: Dear Johannes and Daleif,  thank you so much for your comments. I am ashamed to admit that I probably put these two lines in there, in an attempt to solve a problem I encountered recently. The document structure as well as the style were written by a very generous friend quite a while ago, but I made minor changes on the way. I crossed out both lines 
%\let\counterwithout\relax
%\let\counterwithin\relax
and this solved the problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: What should we do with the question now?